# Ubuntu 16.04 Won't Boot Fresh Install

Tags: boot

I just did a fresh Ubuntu install on my PC and Ubuntu won't boot.

Here is my boot-repair info.

[Boot-Repari info](http://paste2.org/9wydW5Gs)

Comment: Did you use a USB Flash Drive for the first boot?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have standalone Ubuntu on you PC or dual boot?
I ran into same issue on dual boot and had to use recover mode through GRUB boot loader. Select advanced options for ubuntu and recovery mode. 
You can then choose on of the following options:

- resume
- clean (cleans the file system to free up some space)
- dpkg (repairs packages)
- failsafex (boots in faseve graphics mode)
- fcsk (scans file stystem for errors)
- grub (updates the grub boot loader)
- root (takes you to root shell prompt)
- network (enables networking)

I will recommend using dpkg first to see if it finds any packages that need to be repaired, if this doesn't help then failsafex, fcsk, clean and grub.

If none helps then you can consider reinstalling through usb or CD.